# getting object from parse into array and converting into strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, xcode7

I'm trying to fetch data from parse. that have 4-5 fields in string format and display them in the dropdown menu of IOS storyboard.

there are actually 9 columns including parse default columns. they create data,ACL, Object ID so and so forth.

I'm need to fetch only those fields from parse which are in string format and i want display them as a dropdown menu in UIViewController. for dropdown i'm UITableViewController.
serviceview.h

```
@interface ServiceViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *selectionArray;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *servicepicker;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewCars;

@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *customerCars;

- (IBAction)customerCarBtn:(id)sender;
```

serviceview.m

```
@interface ServiceViewController ()

@end

@implementation ServiceViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tableViewCars.delegate = self;
    self.tableViewCars.dataSource = self;
     _selectionArray = @[@"Car Service", @"Brake Pads", @"Car Battery", @"Alternator",@"Starter Motor",@"Timing Belt",@"Cooling System",@"Clutch Repair",@"Repair-Others"];
    NSString *uType = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"email"];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"customerCars"];
    [query whereKey:@"cEmail" containsString:uType];
    NSLog(@"%@",uType);
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *customerCar, NSError *error) {
        if (customerCar) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)customerCar.count);
            for (PFObject *objects in customerCar) {
                NSLog(@"%@", objects.objectId);
                _customerCars = @[objects];
                self.customerCars = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@[objects], nil];
               // NSLog(@"%@",[_customerCars.objectId]);
            }
            //NSLog(customerCars);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.customerCars count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [self.customerCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

    //cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewCars cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    self.tableViewCars.hidden = YES;

}


- (IBAction)customerCarBtn:(id)sender {

    if (self.tableViewCars.hidden == YES) {
        self.tableViewCars.hidden = NO;
    }

    else
        self.tableViewCars.hidden = YES;


}
```

Comment: means u want only that fields that have values in string format.

Comment: Have u got a solution or not?

Comment: @HardikShekhat yes I have got the solution. Used NSDictionary to realise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects being stored in your `customerCars` array, are of type `PFObject`, because that is what Parse returns.

In order to obtain the String value from one of your Parse properties of a car, access it as a dictionary key on the object.

For example, say you wanted to update the cell text label to display the 'colour' property of a car. You would use something like:

```
PFObject *car = [self.customerCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - %@", car[@"make"], car[@"model"]];
```

Comment: The parse should return 5 rows of data, I want store every single record in the NSString format how can archive this.

Comment: Every row of data that is returned is in the form of a PFObject, it is not a String. To turn it into an NSString, get the values from the object, then append them together. What are the properties (columns) for each row of data in your Parse database?

Comment: objectId, <String>make, <String>model, <String>year, <String>cEmail, <String>createdAt, <Date>updatedAt, <Date>ACL, ACL rego<String>                   the above are the columns in have in my parse. I needs to fetch make, model, rego, year.

Comment: @JoydeepSarkar plz also share parse DB structure screenshot.So we can see and understand actual issue easily.

Comment: I added to my example a way to create a string from the make and model of the car.

Comment: @DavidWilliames thanks a lot for your help. . the code was really helpful however I used NSDictionary to realise it.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check on parse for field that have values in string format.

Then you have to use PFQuery's selectKeys method and pass keyNames in array to fetch only selected Keys from parse like this :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"customerCars"];
[query whereKey:@"cEmail" containsString:uType];
[query selectKeys:@[@"column1",@"column2",@"column3"]];
```